# Laravel ошибка при миграции

Tags: php, laravel

Пытаюсь выполнить миграцию 1 таблицы, но не дает.

Код миграции:

```
    <?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateUsersTable extends Migration
{
    /**
     * Run the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function up()
    {
        Schema::create('users', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('login');
            $table->string('first_name');
            $table->string('second_name');
            $table->string('patronymic');
            $table->string('full_name');
            $table->string('phone');
            $table->string('email');
            $table->integer('group');
            $table->string('password');
            $table->rememberToken();
            $table->timestamps();        });
    }

    /**
     * Reverse the migrations.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function down()
    {
        Schema::dropIfExists('users');
    }
}
```

Выдает следующую ошибку:

> SQLSTATE[42S01]: Base table or view already exists: 1050 Table 'roles' already exists

Ради интереса удалила все файлы миграций из папок, история повторяется. Впервые вижу такое.

Answer (score 2):

Уважаемая Аделина всё довольно просто, я уверен что Вы уже разобрались, но пожалуйста:
В ошибке указанно, что одна из таблиц которую Вы пытаетесь создать уже есть, вероятно Вы изменили код метода Schema::create()  таблицы 'role', с таблицей user всё нормально. В этом случае либо пересоздайте все таблицы (при разработке это обычная практика) с помощью:

```
php artisan migrate:refresh // эта команда сбросит и перезапишет все миграции
```

Либо просто удалите таблицу из базы данных и запустите миграцию снова. Надеюсь, что смог помочь!)) И от меня Вам первый лайк!

Comment: Спасибо большое за ответ! Файл был создан командой php artisan:make migrate.